# Dual monitor setup on 2019 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport, dual-screen

I currently have a 16 inch 2019 MBP with an Intel CPU and an Intel UHD 630 integrated GPU. OS is Monterey 12.6.2

I was looking at purchasing the [Dell U2723QE](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-ultrasharp-27-4k-usb-c-hub-monitor-u2723qe/apd/210-bdpf/monitors-monitor-accessories) which I'll call Monitor 1. This monitor supports DisplayPort MST for daisy-chaining to another monitor but from what I understand MacOS doesn't support this and it only ends up mirroring the first display onto the second display in a daisy-chained connection setup. My other monitor is a Dell that supports DisplayPort 1.4 and has a max resolution of 1440p which I'll call Monitor 2.

1. Can my MBP support two monitors through two individual USB-C ports? [This link](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?locale=en_US#:%7E:text=FaceTime%20HD%20camera-,Video%20Support,-Simultaneously%20supports%20full) suggests it should work.
2. If so would this be setup as MBP USB-C port 1 --> Monitor 1 USB-C and then MBP USB-C port 2 --> Monitor 2 DisplayPort?
3. Would these be extended displays so that each window is independent of the other? Can the MBP support two different resolutions being output?
4. Lastly, since Monitor 1 has a USB-C hub if I connect an ethernet cable to the hub will that connectivity pass through to the MBP?
5. What about charging through USB-C? [This link](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-bm/000200094/dell-ultrasharp-27-4k-usb-c-hub-monitor-u2723qe-monitor-usage-and-troubleshooting-guide#:%7E:text=USB%2DC%20cable%3F-,The%20USB%2DC,-port%20on%20your) says that only laptops that support PD over USB-C are supported. I'm assuming my laptop has that since I currently charge my laptop through a USB-C cable but just wanted to confirm this wasn't anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This monitor uses 10 Gb/s USB, which would not be as good as 40 Gb/s Thunderbolt. However, Thunderbolt capabilities would result in a higher price.

1. Can my MBP support two monitors through two individual USB-C ports? [This link](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809?locale=en_US#:%7E:text=FaceTime%20HD%20camera-,Video%20Support,-Simultaneously%20supports%20full) suggests it should work.

> Yes.

2. If so would this be setup as MBP USB-C port 1 --> Monitor 1 USB-C and then MBP USB-C port 2 --> Monitor 2 DisplayPort?

> Yes, but in order to use the USB and ethernet on Monitor 1, you would need a second MBP USB-C port 1 --> Monitor 1 USB-C cable.

3. Would these be extended displays so that each window is independent of the other? Can the MBP support two different resolutions being output?

> Yes and Yes

4. Lastly, since Monitor 1 has a USB-C hub if I connect an ethernet cable to the hub will that connectivity pass through to the MBP?

> Yes

5. What about charging through USB-C? [This link](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-bm/000200094/dell-ultrasharp-27-4k-usb-c-hub-monitor-u2723qe-monitor-usage-and-troubleshooting-guide#:%7E:text=USB%2DC%20cable%3F-,The%20USB%2DC,-port%20on%20your) says that only laptops that support PD over USB-C are supported. I'm assuming my laptop has that since I currently charge my laptop through a USB-C cable but just wanted to confirm this wasn't anything special.

> The monitor will charge the MBP.

---

While Thunderbolt (at 40 Gb/s) can easily transfer video, audio, USB and ethernet using a single USB Type-C cable, this is also possible without using Thunderbolt. However, according to the [manual](https://dl.dell.com/content/manual12109242-dell-u2723qe-monitor-user-s-guide.pdf?language=en-us), Monitor 1 does not attempt to do so. The USB and ethernet uses a single USB Type-C cable. There are options for the video and audio, but you probably what to use another USB Type-C cable because this would also include PD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What did you mean by "you might want to consider separate cables"? I was planning on using two individual cables in that example. One would be USB-C to USB-C and the other would be USB-C to DisplayPort. Each cable would take up an individual USB-C port on the MBP.

Comment: After reading the [manual](https://dl.dell.com/content/manual12109242-dell-u2723qe-monitor-user-s-guide.pdf?language=en-us) for Monitor 1, I updated my answer.  Basically, you would run two (USB-C/USB-C) cables between the MBP and Monitor 1 and a single (USB-C/DisplayPort) cable between the MBP and Monitor 2.